# Applying binary map gives NaN in some columns of the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataset

I have a dataset named Housing having some string values in some columns as shown below:

[image]

I need to convert those 'yes' or 'no' values to 0 or 1. To do that I am using the following code snippet:

```
varlist =  ['mainroad', 'guestroom', 'basement', 'hotwaterheating', 'airconditioning', 'prefarea']

# Defining the map function
def binary_map(x):
    return x.map({"yes": 1, "no": 0})

# Applying the function to the housing list
housing[varlist] = housing[varlist].apply(binary_map)
housing.head()
```

However instead of 1 or 0 as entries I am getting NaN in those columns:
[image]

Can someone tell what is the mistake here?

Answer (score 1):

It is strange, your code is working. If u are reading DF from a file, or writing it into the file, maybe it is an issue.

I only generate DF randomly, the following code is working. Please run it on another file. Maybe it helps u to find the problem.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

varlist = ['mainroad', 'guestroom', 'basement', 'hotwaterheating', 'airconditioning', 'prefarea']

data = {col: [random.choice(["yes", "no"]) for _ in range(5)] for col in varlist}
housing = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(housing)

def binary_map(x):
    return x.map({"yes": 1, "no": 0})

housing[varlist] = housing[varlist].apply(binary_map)
housing.head()
print(housing)
```

Output:

```
  mainroad guestroom basement hotwaterheating airconditioning prefarea
0      yes        no      yes              no              no      yes
1      yes       yes      yes              no              no      yes
2       no        no      yes             yes             yes      yes
3      yes        no      yes              no             yes       no
4      yes       yes       no             yes              no       no
   mainroad  guestroom  basement  hotwaterheating  airconditioning  prefarea
0         1          0         1                0                0         1
1         1          1         1                0                0         1
2         0          0         1                1                1         1
3         1          0         1                0                1         0
4         1          1         0                1                0         0
```